# shuffling array one back

Tags: java, arrays

Basically I have a simple question like this that I'm having a trouble figuring out. I know how to shuffle an array but not really sure how to get it to shuffle specifically to a places like one back.

**The question:**

An array (which is fully populated) is being used as a circular buffer. Write a code fragment in JAVA that will shuffle all elements of the array back one, and move the last element to the front of the rotated array. (No outputs)

**Example 1:**

int[] array = new int[] {1, 2, 3};
array will become {3, 1, 2}

Thanks!

Comment: This sounds like shifting, not shuffling.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
public int[] shiftLeft(int[] nums) {
    if (nums == null || nums.length <= 1) {
        return nums;
    }
    int start = nums[0];
    System.arraycopy(nums, 1, nums, 0, nums.length - 1);
    nums[nums.length - 1] = start;
    return nums;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // 1,2,3
 // 3,2,1
 // 3,1,2

 public int[] swapLastIndex(int[] array) {
    if(array.length < 2) return array;   
    for(int i=0; i<array.length; i++)
        swap(i, array.length-1);    
    return array;
 }

 private void swap(int x, int y) {
    int tmp = array[x];
    array[x] = array[y];
    array[y] = tmp;
 }
```